# twitter package in R maximum tweets using searchTwitter()

Tags: r, twitter

IN Twitter Package in R maximum number of tweets which can be retrieved is 1500.
If i want to retrieve 5000 i get

```
      a<-searchTwitter("#cricket",n=5000)
      Error in out$error : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Is there any way which will help in getting more tweets for particular keyword

Comment: Please provide a _reproducible_ example

Comment: have you authenticated with the Twitter API via OAuth?

Comment: i tried via ROAuth package but still same error

Answer (score 3):

If you are not authenticated then 1500 is the limit imposed by the Twitter API (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search), though your error message is not the same as mine, which is strange:

```
          install.packages("twitteR")
          library(twitteR)
          BBC <- searchTwitter("BBC", n=1500)
          length(BBC)
          [1] 1500
          BBC <- searchTwitter("BBC", n=5000)
          Error in .self$twFromJSON(out) : Error: Invalid query
```

Comment: That's the Twitter API telling you that you've reached the max number of tweets that you're allowed to grab at any one time.

Comment: This is deprecated now that all API calls must be authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

The 1500 limit is imposed by the `twitteR` package, the API's limitations are based on a number of request in 15 minute windows. It is explained [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting).