# Error when search hashtag by range date twitteR

Tags: r, twitter

I use twitteR library for grabbing twitter data

```
library(twitteR)
data<-searchTwitter("#hashtag", n=20000, since='2013-1-20')
```

But I got error like this

```
Warning message:
In doRppAPICall("search/tweets", n, params = params, retryOnRateLimit = retryOnRateLimit,  :
  20000 tweets were requested but the API can only return 32
```

How can I resolve that?

Comment: I think you want to get the twitter history data, not trending data, I havent tried yet, this post may help you because it's similar with your questions [Twitter search Limit in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313431/search-twitter-and-obtain-tweets-by-hashtag-maximizing-number-of-returned-searc),
and one more twitter provide like data grant for researcher to access twitter data, you can find it on twitter but i dont know it's still opened or not.